# How do I update the locations of multiple markers in google maps using phonegap

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, google-maps-api-3

i'm newbie, i have service tracking multi car, i use timmer for receive location, but i dont know how to update old marker with new value. i'm try use delete all marker then add again, but it not smooth. plz help me. Sr for bad english

```
var markers = [];
var marker = [];

setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:24074/WebService1.asmx/DoWork",
            data: {}, 
            dataType: "xml",
            crossDomain: true,
            processData: false,
            success: function (xml) {
                var bienSo, soHieu, soCho, vd, kd;
                $(xml).find('T_XeOnline').each(function () {
                    $(this).find("KinhDo").each(function () {
                        kd = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("ViDo").each(function () {
                        vd = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("BienSoXe").each(function () {
                        bienSo = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("SoHieuXe").each(function () {
                        soHieu = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("SoCho").each(function () {
                        soCho = $(this).text();
                    });
                    content = '<p>Biển số xe: ' + bienSo + '<br/>' +
                               'Số hiệu xe: ' + soHieu + '<br/>' +
                               'Số chỗ: ' + soCho + '<br/>' + '</p>';

                    updateMarker(vd, kd);
                });


            },
            error: function (msg, textStatus) {
                alert("Error " + msg.responseText + "" + msg.statusText + "" + XMLHttpRequest.stat);
            }
        })
    }, 5000);

 function updateMarker(lat, lng) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    addInfoWindow(marker, content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no build-in function for that, but you can build you own by using the `setPosition(latlng)` function to update the markers' positions, and use `setTimeout(myFun, delay)` to wait and make it looks like it is animated.

I created the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dc6j3c79/2/).

Hopefully this help.